# SQL extended events : Events to capture between sp_statement_completed and rpc_completed?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL extended events, are there events that can be captured after sp_statement_completed but before rpc_completed?  We are noticing some differences in the duration times of sp_statement_completed and rpc_completed and I want to determine what could be 'in the middle' causing the differences.

We are using Azure SQL, so I suspect that there is going to be some sort of latency there, but not as much as we are experiencing.  We have also run a similar test on-prem and have NOT noticed and major duration differnces.

Comment: Possibly it's just the network latency when passing back a `DONE` packet. What's the ping time on-prem vs Azure?

Comment: How big of a difference?

Comment: The sp_statement_completed shows a duration of around 100 microseconds, the rpc_completed is showing a duration of around 3,000 microseconds.

Comment: 0.1 milliseconds and 3 milliseconds... so how much lag is between you and Azure?

Comment: Makes perfect sense. RTT to Azure at 3ms would be very decent. Honestly I wouldn't worry about it, it's a tiny amount.